# shifting a javascript array from multidimesional to associative

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array I pulled from a local database.

```
var data = [
  ['09-08-2017', '62154', 'Approved'],
  ['09-08-2017', '62155', 'Approved'],
  ['08-25-2017', '61922', 'Approved'],
  ['08-25-2017', '61923', 'Approved'],
  ['08-18-2017', '61949', 'Approved'],
  // ...
];
```

... and so on and so forth for around 250 different entries.

data[0][0] is the date of the week of the job, each of our weeks correspond to the friday of the week.

data[0][1] is the job number, each job number is unique but there can be multiple job numbers per week.

data[0][2] is the job State each job state needs to stay with the corresponding job number.

What I am essentially trying to do is convert the array from the way it is to a shifted array that has all the job numbers and states associated with the corresponding job data.

something like this possibly:

```
data['09-08-2017'] = ['62154', 'Approved'], ['62155', 'Approved'];
```

or even an object if possible

```
data['09-08-2017'] = { jobNumber: '62154', jobState: 'Approved' };
```

but I'm not even one hundred percent sure how to initialize something like that, and I'm even less sure what would be a decent way to convert it. I'm open for any help or advice possible. Thank you in advance!

**EDIT:**
 I found out why my array was at first formatted so strangely.  When I was first figuring out how to transfer an array from php to javascript I saw that someone had been using

```
var data = <?php json_encode(print_r($data)); ?> ;
```

So I decided to try it and it worked, but apparently it gave me a strange format that was hard to use. So I did some more research and changed it to

```
var data = <?php echo json_encode(array_values($data)); ?>;
```

and now it works and also gives me a more easily workable format for my array.

Comment: please add the array in literal notation.

Comment: What do you mean? the array is converted from php to javascript with json_encode so if I need to change the array format,  that's another bridge I will have to cross.

Comment: What do you want the end result to look like? You can't have what you describe (`data['09-08-2017'] = [ jobNumber: '62154, jobState: 'Approved']`), because you have more than one entry for the same date in your example data.

Comment: That's my issue, I don't mind what the final result looks like. I just need a way to refer to the date and from there pull all the the corresponding job-numbers and from there all the job-states that correspond with the numbers. I was just throwing suggestions because I'm still getting comfortable with JavaScript. if you can give me another possible way that would also be great.

Comment: There are no associative arrays in JavaScript, and your notation `[ jobNumber: '62154, jobState: 'Approved']` is confused (syntactically invalid). What do you really want?

Comment: The only thing I really need is for the job date to be associated with the job number and the job number to be associated with job state. if I need all the jobs for 09-08-2017 I could possibly just look for  data.indexOf('09-08-2017') and then just find the job numbers and job states of the date. if that makes any sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could transform the arrays by iterating the outer array and build arrays with the date. Then push a new object.

```js
var data = [['09-08-2017', '62154', 'Approved'], ['09-08-2017', '62155', 'Approved'], ['08-25-2017', '61922', 'Approved'], ['08-25-2017', '61923', 'Approved'], ['08-18-2017', '61949', 'Approved']],
    object = data.reduce(function (r, a) {
        (r[a[0]] = r[a[0]] || []).push({ jobNumber: a[1], jobState: a[2] });
        return r;
    }, Object.create(null));

console.log(object);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: I believe most of the work was to reformat that array. :D

Comment: @BertrandMarron, sometimes, sometimes it more a question what the op want.

Comment: That looks wonderful, It's a little difficult to wrap my mind around, but I will work around with it until I can implement it. The snippet does exactly what I need it to though.

Comment: I'm not stone set in anything, unfortunately that's the format it turned into initially when I had it translated from php to javascript through json_encode. It definitely is a lot more workable now.

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript doesn't have "associative arrays," it has objects and (as of ES2015) `Map`.

It sounds like you want to turn your array of arrays into an object with properties named after the date, whose values are objects with the job number and state. If so, you use `{}` to create the objects, e.g.:

```
var obj = {};
```

...and set properties on them, with brackets notation for the dates, since they're not valid identifier names:

```
obj["09-08-2017"] = {};
```

You can create the subordinate objects with object initializers, so:

```
obj[entry[0]] = {
    jobNumber: entry[1],
    jobState:  entry[2]
};
```

However, you can't have that structure, because you have more than one entry for the same date. You could have

```
{
    "08-09-2017": {
        12345: "Approved",
        67894: "Approved"
    }
}
```

E.g.:

```js
var data = [
    ["09-08-2017", 62154, "Approved"],
    ["09-08-2017", 12345, "Approved"],
    ["08-08-2017", 62155, "Approved"]
];
var obj = {};
data.forEach(function(entry) {
    var date = entry[0];
    if (!obj[date]) {
        obj[date] = {};
    }
    obj[date][entry[1]] = entry[2];
});
console.log(obj);
```